# Send SMS from multiple extensions using RingCentral API

Tags: api, sms, mms, ringcentral

I have a web application that sends SMSs through RingCentral's APIs, but I am only able to sign in and to send SMSs with my account's main number. I would love to send SMSs from many of my extensions mainly to be able to send more SMSs. How can I choose the extension from which I send a SMS?

Answer (score 0):

A RingCentral extension represents a user so to send SMS from different extensions, you will need an access token for each extension or user. There are a few ways to do this.

- Password flow (server-side): If you are using a private app with password flow, you can bootstrap the system with static passwords for each extension. After the initial bootstrap you can use the refresh tokens to continue to receive active access tokens.
- Auth Code flow (client-side): If you have end users with UI apps, your app can present an OAuth login to retrieve an access token for the user and then use refresh tokens afterwards. This will work with private and public apps.